# How to compile kscope on windows system?

Tags: open-source, cygwin, kde-plasma

kscope is a very nice gui tool on unix to analysis of sorce code i am using it for a while on my linux box.
is there is any port of kscope on windows availbale?
I know cygwin support kde env. but i am not able to compile kde on it.

Comment: finally I have give up for Kscope to compile on Windows.
But I got something good. 
Its called exVim. Its a customized version of gvim and can do most of the feature kscope have.

http://code.google.com/p/exvim 

is the link

Answer (score 1):

May be release 1.9.x are better prepared to be installed on Windows as it is Qt based. (No KDE required).

Farouk

Comment: i tried that but it didn't worked on my pc:(.
very difficult to compile and even after its giving seg fault:(.
i think i should stick to cscope only:)